# The trace theorem for Robin-boundary operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, boundary-value-problem

I am asking about the surjectivity of the Robin-boundary trace operator i.e.,
\begin{align} \mathcal{L}:& C^2(\overline{\Omega}) \to C(\partial \Omega)\\
\mathcal{L} \varphi:&=\partial_n \varphi+ \beta \varphi,
\end{align}

where $C(\partial \Omega)$ (resp. $C^2(\overline{\Omega})$)  is the space of continuous (resp. classe $C^2$) functions on (the sufficiently smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$ of the bounded domain $\Omega$, $\beta \geq 0$ and $\partial_n$ is the normal derivative over a normal vector n.
My question is whether this operator is surjective or not? In particular it is also surjective if we take the case of Neumann boundary conditions (i.e., with $\beta=0$)?
If someone have a reference or any idea/a counter-example?

**Remark**
We can replace $C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ by the domain of the Laplace operator (without boundary conditions) in the space $C(\overline{\Omega})$

Comment: What is $C$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar I added the details. C(Omega) is the space of continuous functions. Thank you!

Comment: So $\partial_n$ is in the distribution sense?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yeah the gradient is in the distribution sense.

Comment: Please give a rigorous definition of $\partial_n \varphi$. In my opinion, this is not possible with only $\varphi \in C(\bar\Omega)$.

Comment: @grew I apologize for the miss understanding. The operator $\mathcal{L}$ is closed with the maximal domain i.e., the set of $\varphi \in C(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $\partial_n \varphi$ exists in $C(\partial \Omega),$ and we can take for example $C(\overline{\Omega}) \cap H^1 (\Omega)$ or even $C^2(\overline{\Omega})$. I need just the domain where it is subjective (the domain will be equipped with the graph norm which is corresponding to the Laplacian without the boundary conditions in my case).. I hope that now my question is complete.. Thank you!